# Manually implementing approximation functions

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, approximation

I have a dataset from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/selfishgene/historical-hourly-weather-data/data) of 45,253 rows and a single column for temperature in Kelvin for the city of Detroit. It's mean = 282.97, std = 11, min = 243.48, max = 308.05.

This is the result when plotted as a histogram of 100 bins with density=True: 
[image: distribution of the data]

I am expected to write the following two functions and see whichever one approximates the closest to the histogram:
[image: PX(x)=(1/sqrt(2πσ^2)*e^(−(x−μ)^2/2σ^2), μ=283K, σ=11K]
[image]

Like this one here using scipy.stats.norm.pdf:
[image: histogram of the data with a curve approximation]

I generated the above image using:

```
x = np.linspace(dataset.Detroit.min(), dataset.Detroit.max(), 1001)
P_norm = norm.pdf(x, dataset.Detroit.mean(), dataset.Detroit.std())

plot_pdf_single(x, P_norm)
```

However, whenever I try to implement any of the two approximation functions all of my values for P_norm result in 0s or infs.

This is what I tried:

```
P_norm = [(1.0/(np.sqrt(2.0*pi*(std*std))))*np.exp(((-x_i-mu)*(-x_i-mu))/(2.0*(std*std))) for x_i in x]
```

I also broke it down into parts for a single x_i:

```
part1 = ((-x[0] - mu)*(-x[0] - mu)) / (2.0*(std * std))
part2 = np.exp(part1)
part3 = 1.0 / (np.sqrt(2.0 * pi * (std*std)))
total = part3*part2
```

I got the following values:

```
1145.3913234604413
inf
0.036267480036493875
inf
```

Comment: please try `-(x_i-mu)*(x_i-mu)`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. It is surprising how a simple minus can make a difference between 0 and infinity...

Answer (score 0):

Since both of the equations use the same formula:

```
def pdf_approximation(x_i, mu, std):
    return (1.0 / (np.sqrt(2.0 * pi * (std*std)))) * np.exp((-(x_i-mu)*(x_i-mu)) / (2.0 * (std*std)))
```

The code for the first approximation is:

```
mu = 283
std = 11

P_norm = np.array([pdf_approximation(x_i, mu, std) for x_i in x])

plot_pdf_single(x, P_norm)
```

[image]

The code for the second approximation is:

```
mu1 = 276
std1 = 6
mu2 = 293
std2 = 6.5

P_norm = np.array([(pdf_approximation(x_i, mu1, std1) * 0.5) + (pdf_approximation(x_i, mu2, std2) * 0.5) for x_i in x])

plot_pdf_single(x, P_norm)
```

[image]